# How to loop over a linked-list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a function that turns an array to a linked list for further usage

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
    } ListNode;



ListNode * create_linked_list(int *nums , int count)
{
    
    ListNode * ptr = (ListNode*)malloc(count*sizeof(ListNode));
    for (int i =0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ListNode new;
        new.val = nums[i];
        ptr[i] = new;
    }

    for (int j=0; j < count; j++)
    {
        if ( j>=count )
            ptr[j].next = NULL;
        else
            ptr[j].next = &ptr[j+1];
    } 

    return ptr;
}
int main()
{
    int nums[] = {2,4,3};
    ListNode *node_ptr = create_linked_list(nums , sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]));
    ListNode start = node_ptr[0];
}
```

I have this simple function that turns an array of integers into a linked list, assume the last node in the list is called `x_node` now `x_node.next` is equal to `NULL` because it is defined inth the second for loop in `create_linked_list`, but when I try to add a while loop in the main it results  in a segmentation fault

```
int main()
{
    int nums[] = {2,4,3};
    ListNode *node_ptr = create_linked_list(nums , sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]));
    ListNode start = node_ptr[0];
    while (start.next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \n", start.val);
        start = *start.next; // at the last element it should stop but a segfault is thrown 
        
    }

}
```

Comment: `if ( j>=count )` this condition will never be hit because the `for` loop terminates (without executing the body) when `j` reaches `count`. It should be `if (j == count - 1)`. Or just terminate the loop at `count-1` and set the last node outside the loop: `ptr[count-1].next = NULL`;

Comment: `(ListNode*)malloc(count*sizeof(ListNode));`  This it not how linked lists work. If you allocate memory for an array of nodes, you cannot benefit from main feature of linked lists. You cannot free any node without freeing the whole block of memory. You cannot add more nodes either, as `realloc` might make all your internal pointers invalid. Also in C you should not cast the result of `malloc` and friends. I suggest you get hands on a decent C text book or tutorial on a website to check how linked lists are supposed to be done.

Comment: @kaylum you mean `ptr[count-1].next = NULL`

Comment: @Gerhardh oh i know this very well but I am kind of a newbie to c programming so explain with an example on how to do this properly will be much appreciated

Comment: You need to `malloc` memory for each node on its own instead of one allocation for all of them. Any tutorial should contain a valid example how to create a list. That would be a bit too much for a comment and as it does not really touch the problem in your question, it shouldn't go into an answer as well. BTW: I am a bit puzzled by the combination of "I know this very well" and "I am new to C and would like an example". ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh why are you puzzled

Comment: Because if you are aware how lists work, why do you need an example to show it?

Answer (score 0):

If you wan t to loop over a linked list, you need to create the list properly in the first place. Your `create_linked_list` function is totally wrong.

You want this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
  int val;
  struct ListNode* next;
} ListNode;


ListNode* create_linked_list(int* nums, int count)
{
  ListNode* head = NULL;
  ListNode *previous = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    // create new node and put value into it
    ListNode *new = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    new->val = nums[i];
    new->next = NULL;

    if (i == 0)  // head will point to the first element
      head = new;

    if (previous)
    {
      // if previous node exists, link to newly created node
      previous->next = new;
    }
    previous = new;   // new node becomes previous node
  }

  return head;
}

int main()
{
  int nums[] = { 2,4,3 };
  ListNode* head = create_linked_list(nums, sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]));

  // now it's up to you to write the print_list function
  // print_list(head);
}
```

Now writing the `print_list` function should be easy. Hint: take a pencil and a piece if paper and draw the nodes with arrows as pointers pointing to the next node.

Comment: I figured it out but in your example you don't free the allocated memory which causes a leak right?